# How to solve "Windows cannot access the specified device, path, or file. You may not have the appropriate permission to access the item." error

Tags: windows, windowserror

When I try to install and use CoppeliaSim Edu on my laptop it gives the error:

> Windows cannot access the specified device, path, or file. You may not
> have the appropriate permission to access the item.

The program runs normally when I launch the program from the installation setup at the end of the installation. (By checking the checkbox with the prompt "Launch program now" on the window with the Finish installation button.) But when I close the program and try to rerun the program, an error message with this text pops up.

Google suggested that this could be because of a permission issue, so I gave permission to everyone I could from the window but it still did not work. I'm confused because I have no idea why this is. I cannot open this program in any way unless I reinstall the program. Any kind of advice or tips is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Can you verify if the installation path is "C:\Program Files (x86)" or "C:\Program Files"?

You can check it on the properties from the shortcut of "CoppeliaSim Edu" that is created in your desktop and, then look for it in "C:\Program Files (x86)" or "C:\Program Files". Depending on the one that you have the real installation, ensure that the icon in the desktop has the same, normally it means to change it from "C:\Program Files (x86)" to "C:\Program Files" or backwards, depending in the one that you have in the desktop icon.

I hope it is useful for you.

Regards.

Comment: Yes. Both the file paths are the same. And it’s not just the shortcut that does not work. When I go to the install location and try to run the app, it still does not work.